# Запуск скрипта с параметрами через крон

Tags: php, cron

Нашел на просторах интернета решение как передать параметры в скрипт при запуске через крон.в итоге получилось следующее:

```
/bin/php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php?task=delivery >/dev/null 2>&1
```

но крон возврашает

```
Exited with return code = 127
```

Если обратиться к скрипту через браузер-все хорошо.что не так?права на доступ есть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Крон - это не обычный HTTP-запрос. Это вообще **другая среда выполнения**. Там нет ничего подобного `cron_run.php?task=delivery`. Для того окружения, где это выполняется, это все является путем к файлу, потому что часть `?task=delivery` воспринимается как параметры только в URL (URL, напомнию, описывает *ресурс*, в том числе, каким транспортом можно этот ресурс получить - в случае с веб-ресурсом это HTTP), а шелл и интерпретатор ожидают просто путь к файлу, без схем, параметров и прочего веселья.

У вас есть два пути. Первый, которым вы скорее всего зря воспользуетесь - это запускать wget по крону и бить им конкретный URL:

```
/usr/bin/wget -qO- http://google.com/cron.php?task=delivery
```

Второй путь, который является путем для всех программистов выше нижней планки - это воспользоваться тем окружением, в котором происходит вызов, и параметры запуска через аргументы командной строки (прошу простить, если php на самом деле лежит не в `/usr/bin/`):

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php delivery --verbose
                                 ^        ^
                                 $argv[0] $argv[1]
```

В этом случае их можно получить из глобального массива `$argv`.

Comment: можете подсказать как на Open Server поставить задачу в крон?а то уже надоело хост насиловать,

Comment: сделал как вы писали,все-равно возвращает то же самое...

Comment: нет, я не работаю с опенсервером

Comment: Даже при попытке запустить пустой скрипт выдает 127. /user/bin/php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php delivery >/dev/null 2>&1 что не так?(пыха лежит по тому пути что вы писали)

Answer (score 1):

> что не так?

То что ты нашел на просторах интернета.

Параметры в скрипт, запускаемый через командную строку, передаются - не поверишь - через командную строку.

Плюс к тому, РНР скрипты исполняет интерпретатор РНР, а не Шелл.

То есть, вызываем как

```
php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php delivery
```

а в скрипте получаем переданный параметр через `$argv[1]`

Answer (score -1):

Вместо /bin/sh попробуйте указать путь до php,

```
/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/skbonus/data/www/beta.skbonus.ru/cron_run.php?task=delivery >/dev/null 2>&1
```

У вас путь до php может отличаться.